# Java - Main method with If statement printing order error

Tags: java

I appoligize in advance if this is a duplicate of any kind, but I couldn't find anything that addressed my specific problem.

Here is my program:

```html
import java.util.Random;

public class CarnivalGame{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int count = 0;
        int wins = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
             System.out.println("Roll " + count);
             count = count + 1;
             int die1=(dieRoll(6));
             int die2=(dieRoll(20));
             int die3=(dieRoll(8));
             int die4=(dieRoll(4));
             int die5=(dieRoll(12));
             int sum = die1+die2+die3+die4+die5;
             System.out.println("Total:    " +  sum + "\n");

             if ((sum >= 35) || (sum < 20)){
             System.out.println("Player wins!\n");
             wins = wins + 1;
     }
     if (count == 100){
    //PROBLEM AREA
     System.out.printf("After 100 rolls, the player has won for a total of %d times!\n", wins); 
     }
    }//end for loop
  }//end main

public static int dieRoll(int sides){ 
   int num = 0;
   int roll = 0;
   Random  rng = new Random(); 
   if(sides >=4){ 
      for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){ 
         roll = rng.nextInt(sides)+1;
         System.out.println("Roll is:  " + roll);
         num = num + roll; 
      }//end for loop
   }//end if
 return num;
  }//end method   
}//end class
```

What it currently prints out:

roll count = 100 in this example

```
For loop (x100):

---> "After 100 rolls, the player has won for a total of (wins) times!" Roll (count)

    Roll is:  dieRoll(x)
    Roll is:  dieRoll(x)
    Roll is:  dieRoll(x)
    Roll is:  dieRoll(x)
    Roll is:  dieRoll(x)
    Total:    sum

    if ((sum >= 35) || (sum < 20))
    "Player wins!"
```

What I'm trying to get it to print out:

Same exact thing but with

```
 if ((sum >= 35) || (sum < 20))
        "Player wins!"
---> "After 100 rolls, the player has won for a total of (wins) times!
```

So basically I'm trying to figure out why my problem area is printing along with the roll count, where it should be printing after the sum and "Player wins!"

I'm assuming it is an error with my if statement formatting, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Indent your code properly, so that you can see how the ifs, fors etc. are nested! Put the code to print the result outside the for-loop. It's now inside the for-loop.

Comment: ok, sorry I have a bad habit of not indenting!

Comment: @nukacola7 If you're on Eclipse, use `Ctrl + i` to indent correctly.

Comment: And please note that Java is not Javascript - so shouldn't be specified as a Javascript snippet.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok thanks for the edit! I will keep that in mind for next time

Comment: @Jesper but if i do that will I be able to only print it specifically on the last roll because the counter variable is within the loop? Or am I missing something here

Comment: `System.out.printf("After 100 rolls, the player has won for a total of %d times!\n", wins);` Why don't you just put this line after the loop. Once the 100 rolls are finished, the loop will terminate and print the results. No need for an `if` statement to check if `count == 100`

Comment: @CalvinP. oh my god you're totally right! For some reason I was thinking it had to be within the loop but it doesn't since I want it to be the last thing printed anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, really stupid logic error on my part. Here is the fix to my problem, as Jesper and Calvin P. suggested, I just had to put the problem area after the for loop. I was thinking I had to keep it within the loop. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CarnivalGame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int count = 0;
int wins = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
System.out.println("Roll " + (i + 1));
count = count + 1;
int die1=(dieRoll(6));
int die2=(dieRoll(20));
int die3=(dieRoll(8));
int die4=(dieRoll(4));
int die5=(dieRoll(12));
int sum = die1+die2+die3+die4+die5;
System.out.println("Total:    " +  sum + "\n");

if ((sum >= 35) || (sum < 20)){
System.out.println("Player wins!\n");
wins = wins + 1;
}
if (count == 100){
//FIXED PROBLEM
System.out.printf("After 100 rolls, the player has won for a total of %d times!\n", wins); 
}
}//end for loop
}//end main

public static int dieRoll(int sides)
{ 
   int num = 0;
   int roll = 0;
   Random  rng = new Random(); 
   if(sides >=4) 
      { 
      for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
         { 
         roll = rng.nextInt(sides)+1;
         System.out.println("Roll is:  " + roll);
         num = num + roll; 
   }//end for loop
   }//end if
return num;
}//end method   

}//end class
```

Comment: Please remember to up-vote any answer that helped you, and accept the one answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your loop has 101 iterations, from 0 to 100. 
So after number 99 your 100 dice rolls are over, and THEN you roll one additional time. Just change the loop to go from 0 to 99 (i<100 instead of 101).

Edit (mostly because I can't answer you directly yet):

As you (try) to iterate 100 times anyway, I don't really see why you would need to have the variable `count` at all. Just let your loop roll the dice a hundred times, add the wins, and then print your statement afterwards.

Comment: Just realized this as well haha. You should use this, but also still move the results to after the loop. Then you can eliminate your `count` variable altogether. Edit: oh and change `System.out.println("Roll " + count);` to `System.out.println("Roll " + (i + 1));`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `count` is always *one ahead* of your iterator variable `i` because you increase it very early in the loop.  So you'll reach count == 100 while `i` is still 99.

Move your output before the increase of count OR increate at the end of the loop maybe.

Comment: does this go along with Christian W's answer? Would what he said fix what you are saying?

Comment: more or less - making sure you never entered the loop again after the output would fix this just as well ;-)